# When can the present tense be used to express "now", neither before nor after?

Tags: present-tense

Recently, questions have been asked questions about how, for instance, the past tense can be used to express a future event, or the simple present can be used to express a continuous action or, lastly, the future tense can be used in reference to the present time.

After reading these questions I began to think about, not complicated things, but when we can use the present tense to express the present tense.

So: as everybody knows, the present tense of the verb *drive* is *drive*; but, for instance:

- in "I used to drive to work but now I don't" the present tense *drive* is clearly used in a past sense;
- in "I will drive you to work tomorrow" the present tense *drive* is clearly used in a future sense;
- in "I would drive if I could afford to" the present tense *drive* is clearly used in a conditional sense;

Since I'm not able to think of another sentence in which the present tense *drive* is used in a present sense - i.e., now, neither before nor after - and I also know that "I drive the car now" is ungrammatical, can anybody suggest one?

Comment: None of those *drive*s is present tense: they're all infinitives used as complement of a modal.

Comment: But simple present is ordinarily used for habitual actions and permanent truths: "I drive to work every morning", "Most people drive too fast", "People in St. Louis drive badly in snow", "He drives a '57 Chevy".

Comment: @Stoney, so I should stop to think about it? Yes, it would be better; but what is a sentence in which "drive" is used in present sense and in reference to "now", not before nor after?

Comment: It's also used in immediate narration - a sportscast for instance: "They're side by side at the turn ... Petty drops down quicker, he's pulling ahead ... and he drives across the finish line just ahead of Baker."

Comment: @Stoney, thank you! I never would have thought about a case like "immediate narretion".

Comment: Oops ... I wanted to write "narration", not "narretion"; sic!

Comment: There's no problem thinking up a present simple context with _now_: _My wife's got a broken arm, so I drive to the shops now. I used to ride my bike to work but I drive the car now._

Comment: What tense is the 'ing' version of a word (I thought it was present tense)?  Coz the most obvious present (now) tense form I can think of is:  'I am driving'.

Comment: @mcalex, as far as I know, "driving" is participle, not present tense.

Comment: @mcalex *VERB-ing* is the present participle which is used in the "progressive" constructions *BE VERB-ing*. If a present form of *BE* is used (*I **am** driving*) the construction is a "present progressive", if a past form is used (*I **was** driving*) it is a "past progressive", if a "perfect" (*HAVE been*) construction is used (*I have/had been driving*) it is a "perfect progressive", and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Your question drives me to provide this answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: He asked for people to suggest a sentence in which the present tense of the verb "drive" is used. I did exactly that. What am I missing?

Comment: @Rookatu It's possible that this doesn't address the OP's question because they were asking about a different sense of *drive*.  Although the question doesn't state this explicitly, all of the examples above are about operating automobiles.

Comment: One sense of the word comes metaphorically from the other, like so many of the words we use. But if it helps, I can make the metaphor explicit by saying that his question is an agent that drives me to that place in my heart where I feel compelled to provide an answer.